# How to update multiple rows by keeping some column values the same and updating others?

Tags: postgresql, case

I am trying to bulk update some rows in postgres. Now not all of the rows need to update the same column values. For example, row 1 needs to update column 1 and 3 whereas row 2 needs to update column 2 and 4. so row 1 column 2 and 4 should not change and row 2 column 1 and 3 should not change.

I have tried using `CASE`s to conditionally `SET` the correct column values but it doesn't work with multiple rows. It DOES work if I only try to update 1 row at a time.

```sql
update topic as tmp set 
"from" = (CASE WHEN tmp2."from2"::text = 'OLD_VALUE' THEN tmp."from"::int2 ELSE tmp2."from2"::int2 end),
"text_search" = (CASE WHEN tmp2."text_search2"::text = 'OLD_VALUE' THEN tmp."text_search"::text ELSE tmp2."text_search2"::text end),
"weight" = (CASE WHEN tmp2."weight2"::text = 'OLD_VALUE' THEN tmp."weight"::numeric ELSE tmp2."weight2"::numeric end)
from (values 
(1051,1,'Electronic Devices',3),
(1052,'OLD_VALUE','OLD_VALUE',100)
)  as tmp2("id2","from2","text_search2","weight2")  
where  tmp2."id2" = tmp."id"
```

This is the error message i get

SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "OLD_VALUE"

When I try with only 1 `FROM` value

```
from (values (1051,1,'Electronic Devices',3))
```

or

```
from (values (1052,'OLD_VALUE','OLD_VALUE',100))
```

it works correctly.

It even works correctly if the same columns need to be updated eg.

```
from (values 
(1051,1,'Electronic Devices',3),
(1052,2,'Topic 2',100)
)
```

Why is it not working correctly when I need to update different columns for each row?

Answer (score 1):

When you provide the list of values as `values (1051,1,'Electronic Devices',3),(1052,'OLD_VALUE','OLD_VALUE',100))`, the first set of values is interpreted as the "template" of data types, and in this case `(1051,1,'Electronic Devices',3)`, it's `int, int, text, int`.  Then, any subsequent values provided, will be expected to have the same data type signature.  When it parses `(1052,'OLD_VALUE','OLD_VALUE',100)`, it sees `int,text,text,int`, which doesn't match the data type signature it expects, so it reports an error.

When you omit the first value and provide only `(1052,'OLD_VALUE','OLD_VALUE',100)`, then it identifies `int,text,text,int` as the "template" data type signature, and it proceeds without complaint.

Comment: Ok thanks, this makes sense. Do you have any idea what I should use instead of this to achieve what I want?

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirements are, or what your design looks like, but it seems like you want to use `OLD_VALUE` as a placeholder.  It seems to do the trick when it comes to `text` types, but when it comes to `int` types, you need something else that will represent `OLD_VALUE` (maybe something like `-1` or `-9999`?).  I don't really have a recommendation without knowing more about what the standards are within your organization.  If it were up to me, I would store the old values somewhere and actually retrieve them in the situation you describe.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend against using keywords like `"from"` as column names--it creates an environment where you can encounter confusion quite easily.

Comment: I need to bulk update multiple rows and the columns can be of different types. I considered using a different placeholder for each different data type but I was trying to get away with a common placeholder. Thanks for the help